# Type deduction of reference_wrappers with Args

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

I have a template function:

```
template<class... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args)
{
    boo<std::decay_t<Args>...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Now what I want to do is to call foo function several times like this:

```
int value = 123;
const int& cr_value = value;
foo(value );
foo(std::cref(value ));
```

In first case I call `boo<int>` in second case `boo<std::const_reference_wrapper<int>>` is called.
Is there way to "dereference" reference_wrapper automaticaly without explicit using of `get` function **for every argument in pack**?
The reason for this is that I want to call `boo<const int&>` in second case, not `boo<std::const_reference_wrapper<int>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do something like:

```
template <typename T> struct unwrap {
    using type = T;
};
template <typename T> struct unwrap<std::reference_wrapper<T>> {
    using type = T&;
};

template <typename T> using unwrap_t = typename unwrap<T>::type;

template<class... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args)
{
    boo<unwrap_t<std::decay_t<Args>>...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/244dd7e6e928a1f7).

Comment: wow. What an awesome use of template using. Never thought that template class can have an alias inside as a nested type.

Comment: It is the traditional way for [type_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits).